# Values of a vector to remain equal to another vector based on conditions

Tags: r

I'm using [this dataset](https://mega.nz/file/sN1AGK7Q#iYyvXaN5XkAhhYwT1RZ12unXveyQZ75Nkc2VoDPLi1k).

I want to create a variable named `neg_gw_shock` such that

```r
neg_gw_shock = (-gw_level_dev) if gw_level_dev < 0 
neg_gw_shock =  NA if gw_level_dev >= 0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't just upload your file to some host service, post a `dput` of your data in your question so people can help you

Comment: You can use the base R ifelse() function. It takes three arguments: a condition, a return value for when the condition is true, and a return value for when the condition is false.

Comment: `your_data$neg_gw_shock = ifelse(your_data$gw_level_dev < 0, -your_data$gw.level.dev, NA)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Your idea worked! However, I tried using this for creating another variable but I got an error:
'x' is NULL so the result will be NULLError in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : 
  replacement has length zero

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
load("...\\water_data_1.rda")
water_data_1 %>%
  mutate(neg_gw_shock = case_when(gw_level_dev < 0 ~ -gw_level_dev,
                                  gw_level_dev >= 0 ~ NA))
```

`case_when` works like a `ifelse` statement, but is vectorised

Comment: ifelse is vectorized, no?

Comment: My bad, per Documentation: "[...] allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements."

Comment: Thank you! But this one showed an error again. In fact this is what I had tried initially but didn't work so I posted this question.

Comment: And what was the error? If you post this, we might be able to help...